# Managing code snippets in the SBT Playground

Tags: ibm-sbt

At Connect 2013 Philippe showed how to login to the playground and select the "Manage" button to get to the page for managing your code snippets. The "Manage" button does not show for me after logging in to the GH playground. Is that feature currently available?

Comment: if you install it on your system, you would have this feature.  the GH Playground is hard coded to work with a set connections server

Answer (score 1):

The 'manage' button only appears if you have the proper rights for editing the configuration. As the playground is a Domino application, this is done by changing the ACL of the database, and requires the user to at least be an 'Editor'.
The instance in Greenhouse only allows a few IBMers to change the configurations. If you want you're own configuration, then you have to deploy your own instance.
That said, the playground allows you to temporarily set a custom configuration. But this is for the current user and it is not persisted.